# Continuity and differentiability of $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Given a function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{x-1}$.

Is $f(x)$ a continuous function.

Is $f(x)$ a differentiable function.

Answer (score 4):

$f$ is defined nowhere except at $1$ where $f(1) = 0$. It is continuous at $x=1$; functions defined at one point are continuous. It is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: if it is continuous at $x=1$ why can't it be differentiable at $x=1$

Comment: @PankajSinha It is continuous in a vacuous sense. It is not differentiable because we can't really construct a difference quotient. Moreover, we want functions differentiable at a point to be defined on an open interval containing that point.

Comment: Shouldn't the same hold true for continuity